# Explanation of parameters in earliest deadline first algorithm

Tags: algorithm, real-time

I am learning the [earliest deadline first algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earliest_deadline_first_scheduling) for my exam but since I don't have any good resources I need to ask for help here.

[image]

[slightly bigger image here](http://img98.imageshack.us/img98/6451/screenshot1si.png)

```
τ1(r0 = 0, C = 3, D = 7, T = 20)

I need to know what this parameters mean, for example:
D - deadline
T - ?
C - ?
```

And so on...

I know this is noobish question but, I will really appreciate if somebody give me the clear simple explanation :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Page 9 (physical) of the textbook you've quoted defines your parameters as:

> - *r*,task release time, i.e. the triggering time of the task execution request
> - *C*,task worst-case computation time, when the processor is fully allocated to it
> - *D*, task relative deadline, i.e. the maximum acceptable delay for its processing
> - *T*, task period

Comment: Thanks, I believe that explanation exists in book, but unfortunately I don't have it, so thanks a lot!